# "Retry Upload" using blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using the blueimp jquery file upload ([github link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)) and to some extend I've been able to customize it to my needs, but I'm stuck with one specific requirement: when a file was not uploaded successfully, it must show a "Retry Upload" button to let the user start it over again. Is there any way to easily implement with any of the available API options?